# Will a phonegap/cordova app that uses external "www" folder be rejected from apple?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

In my iOS phonegap/cordova application , instead of having the "www" folder inside the app bundle , i keep it on my server and the app connects there to run all the html/javascript/css.

I was wondering though.. Will an application like this get rejected?

Because apple states :

**`“Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected“`**

So if i keep it externally that means i could change the code whenever i like.

So its not possible?

Because i read on some tutorials how someone could do that , keep their "www" folder in the server side , so that there wouldnt be need for updating the app through the store.

Comment: More likely to get rejected on grounds that it might as well be a web app

Comment: Yes but i ll be using push notification plugins to enable push. So this isnt the case here. You cant have push with a web app. My concern is if it would get rejected because of running/downloading external code , that is my javascript which i could change whenever i like

Comment: I don't think they care that you need push notifications in your app, there concern is, does the app have value and cannot be achieved just as a website.

Comment: How can you achieve push notifications as a website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [blogpost](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/10/03/phonegap-apple-rejections-uiux-guidelines/). The author has a lot of experience with PhoneGap apps in Apple Appstore and can help eliminating the obvious reject reasons.

I copy here just the main points from the blogpost that adds to whatever is already in iOS UI guidelines and and AppStore review guidelines:

> - If your app is just a web site wrapped in PhoneGap, it will probably get rejected. There are exceptions to this case, but don’t expect that wrapping a web site in a web view will get you into the App Store.
> - If your app requires the user to pinch/zoom/pan to view content (like a web site), it will probably get rejected.  Your apps need to feel like apps.
> - If your app just looks like text on a page with hyperlinks, and has no native-like styles, it will probably get rejected.

Comment: It's a good idea to summarise the points from the post in the answer, in case the linked post goes away.

Answer (score -2):

Apple haven't rejected my app that uses PhoneGap, however they rejected because the app didn't  have great functionalities!haha (however my client wanting something simple)

Comment: Yeah we experienced the same thing.